# Rails, devise and Haml: syntax error, unexpected kELSE

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, devise, haml

I'm trying to set up a simple application for running multiple blogs and my app/views/layouts/application.html.haml file looks like this:

```
!!!
%html
  %head
    %title Brimble's Blogs
    = stylesheet_link_tag    "application", :media => "all"
    = javascript_include_tag "application"
    = csrf_meta_tags

  %body
    %p.notice= notice
    %p.alert= alert

  .user-auth-nav{style => 'float:right'}
    = if user_signed_in?
      = link_to('Edit registration', edit_user_registration_path)
      = link_to('Logout', destroy_user_session_path)
    = else
      = link_to('Login', new_user_session_path)
      = link_to('Register', new_user_registration_path)
    = end

= yield
```

The error I get is:

```
compile error
<myapp>/app/views/layouts/application.html.haml:18: syntax error, unexpected kELSE
<myapp>/app/views/layouts/application.html.haml:22: syntax error, unexpected kEND
<myapp>/app/views/layouts/application.html.haml:23: unknown regexp options - htl
<myapp>/app/views/layouts/application.html.haml:23: syntax error, unexpected $undefined
));}\n  </div>\n</html>\n#{_hamlout.adjust_tabs(-2); _...
                        ^
<myapp>/app/views/layouts/application.html.haml:25: syntax error, unexpected kENSURE, expecting $end
```

Extracted source (around line #18):

```
15:       = link_to('Edit registration', edit_user_registration_path)
16:       = link_to('Logout', destroy_user_session_path)
17:     = else
18:       = link_to('Login', new_user_session_path)
19:       = link_to('Register', new_user_registration_path)
20:     = end
21:
```

I'm following a tutorial on this page:
http://www.logansbailey.com/2011/02/27/adding-authorization-using-devise/
The tutorial uses erb but I really like the idea of Haml so I want to give it a go.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Found the answer

Firstly, I don't need the `= end` and secondly, I changed the `= if` to `- if` and it seems to have stopped complaining.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

for ruby code that is not supposed to output something use `-` instead of `=`:

```
  .user-auth-nav{style => 'float:right'}
    -if user_signed_in?
      =link_to('Edit registration', edit_user_registration_path)
      =link_to('Logout', destroy_user_session_path)
    -else
      =link_to('Login', new_user_session_path)
      =link_to('Register', new_user_registration_path)
```

the `end` tag can be omitted in haml.

Answer (score 1):

When you are using Haml as view engine then you don't use `end`. Write only

```
= if user_signed_in?
  = link_to('Edit registration', edit_user_registration_path)
  = link_to('Logout', destroy_user_session_path)
= else
  = link_to('Login', new_user_session_path)
  = link_to('Register', new_user_registration_path)
```

And it will work. Haml will close block by itself.

**PS**
Also use `-` (dash) instead of `=` on nonprintable code lines like `if` and `else`.